# Позиция bootstrap кнопки

Tags: bootstrap, button

Мне нужно изменить позицию кнопки "Создать событие", что бы она была с правой стороны календаря.
Пробовал через margin и float, но ничего не происходило

Вот сам календарь http://prjct-x.ru/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, вот я в отладчике задал кнопке float: right - она переместилась вправо. Так что флоат вполне себе работает. Или Вам что-то другое надо?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да, нужно было именно это, странно, что у меня работало. А можно ли ещё как дату, которая находится слева, сделать ниже?

Comment: @realHikkan, чтоб кнопка и дата на одном уровне были?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: @realHikkan, нужно в разметке поменять местами дату и кнопку. Т.е. сначала должна идти кнопка со свойством float: right, а затем дата

Comment: Всё сработало, большое спасибо!